# Moving a wall to Increase a room size-- what extra support needed?

Tags: support

I want to increase a room from 10' to 14'  currently there is a  'header' over the 10' span, with a 4 x 4 support; If I increase the span to 14' can I move the 4x4 support or do i need to keep it and add another?

Comment: This has far more to do with what is above the 4x4 than the actual support post.  We would need very clear pictures to help.

Comment: Is the wall you want to open up load-bearing? If it's an outside wall, or it runs at right angles to the floor joists, assume it is... And if it is, you ***need*** to get an engineer to look at it, determine the loading, and compute what additional support is needed.

Comment: @keshlam - I would assume it is load bearing given that it has a 4x4 at the end... or just a builder that likes to frame walls like decks.

Comment: It is load bearing, and I had an engineer provide drawings for the span of 21' however, with a 4x4 post halfway, using a 4x12 header, however we decided to not go 'all the way' to 21' and at 14' we think we should be able to make the 14' span with this header, to accommodate the extra 4 feet.  I don't want to go back to the engineer b/c already paid him $$

Comment: Ann - This really depends.  Maybe he arbitrarily picked a spot for the post because he couldn't go the full 21' span and decided that the spot he picked would work best.  Or maybe the spot was picked because the load is picked up directly below.  You would have to give us all of the information that the engineer got.   On that note if the engineer has already researched your issue and you paid him... it is probably worth $100 to have him draw it up at 14 feet.  If it is easy to do he won't charge you much, if it is hard, well then you needed an engineer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give him a call... I think there was some leeway as to placement, at 10' is where the current post is placed, and he did have us pour a 21" x 21" footer in the basement for support